# string interpolation in media queries

Tags: stylus

I'm expecting this code to turn

```
propMediaQuery(mediaStatement, prop, propResolutionObj)
  for key, value in propResolutionObj
    @media (mediaStatement: value)
      prop value

body
  propMediaQuery(min-width, max-height, { '320px': 140px, '768px': 180px })
```

into

```
body
  @media (min-width: 320px)
    max-height 140px
  @media (min-width: 768px)
    max-height 180px
```

the mediaStatement variable doesn't get interpolated - What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use interpolation in selectors and properties. To remove quotation marks in *key* values you can use `unquote()` function.

**Stylus**

```
propMediaQuery(mediaStatement, prop, propResolutionObj)
  for key, value in propResolutionObj
    @media ({mediaStatement}: unquote(key))
      {prop} value

body
  propMediaQuery(min-width, max-height, { '320px': 140px, '768px': 180px })
```

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  body {
    max-height: 140px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    max-height: 180px;
  }
}
```

Comment: max-height get's interpolated.... it's the media statement variable that doesn't.

Comment: @CatBoss Sorry, I forgot the braces in `mediaStatement` variable. I edit muy answer.